# jQuery click on psuedo after element

Tags: javascript, jquery, pseudo-element

Trying to detect if a pseudo element is clicked, this has been asked before but not quite with my set up. I have other elements inside my wrapper which also have standard click events, so I cannot use `pointer-events: none`

Here is my js function:

```
const $wrapper = $('.wrapper');

attachInformationEvent = function() {
    const $elems = $wrapper.find('table td span');
    $elems.off().on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        if (e.offsetX > $(e.target).width()) {
            // if the click is offset more than the element width then this should be the psuedo after element
            // fire our function here
            console.log('pseudo');
        } else if (event.target.tagName === 'LABEL' || event.target.tagName === 'INPUT'){
            // allow normal checkbox click event
            // this event is firing the pseudo event above
            return;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}();
```

This is the markup:

```
<table id="gridzone_0_Rep_Content_ctl00_1_cbList_1" class="checkbox-group default footable-loaded">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span data-info="Excellence Description">
                    <input id="gridzone_0_Rep_Content_ctl00_1_cbList_1_0_1" type="checkbox" name="gridzone_0$Rep_Content$ctl01$ctl00$cbList$0" value="Excellence">
                    <label for="gridzone_0_Rep_Content_ctl00_1_cbList_1_0_1">Excellence</label>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span data-info="Innovation Description">
                    <input id="gridzone_0_Rep_Content_ctl00_1_cbList_1_1_1" type="checkbox" name="gridzone_0$Rep_Content$ctl01$ctl00$cbList$1" value="Innovation">
                    <label for="gridzone_0_Rep_Content_ctl00_1_cbList_1_1_1">Innovation</label>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span data-info="Care Description">
                    <input id="gridzone_0_Rep_Content_ctl00_1_cbList_1_2_1" type="checkbox" name="gridzone_0$Rep_Content$ctl01$ctl00$cbList$2" value="Care">
                    <label for="gridzone_0_Rep_Content_ctl00_1_cbList_1_2_1">Care</label>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span data-info="Heritage Description">
                    <input id="gridzone_0_Rep_Content_ctl00_1_cbList_1_3_1" type="checkbox" name="gridzone_0$Rep_Content$ctl01$ctl00$cbList$3" value="Heritage">
                    <label for="gridzone_0_Rep_Content_ctl00_1_cbList_1_3_1">Heritage</label>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span data-info="Passion Description">
                    <input id="gridzone_0_Rep_Content_ctl00_1_cbList_1_4_1" type="checkbox" name="gridzone_0$Rep_Content$ctl01$ctl00$cbList$4" value="Passion">
                    <label for="gridzone_0_Rep_Content_ctl00_1_cbList_1_4_1">Passion</label>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And some css to display a small pseudo element after the span:

```
.wrapper table td span::after {
    content: "?";
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    background: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.077rem;
    font-weight: 800;
    height: 1.25rem;
    width: 1.25rem;
    left: 2.5rem;
    top: -1rem;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

I have made a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/1L07amur/).

I feel like this is close, if anyone can advise I would really appreciate it. I am not in a position to be able to change much of the markup unfortunately.

Comment: Long-story short: don't use a pseudo element and just put a real element in there, and move on :)

Comment: `if (e.offsetX > $(this).width()) {` - your pseudo is off the end of the `span` not the checkbox/label  https://jsfiddle.net/05st2nye/

Comment: @freedomn-m I don't have that luxury unfortunately.

Comment: Ah that works! Thank you. If you put that in an answer I can vote on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're using `e.target` with a nested `label` and `checkbox`.

```
<span>
    <input ...
    <label ...
</span>
```

using `$("span").click...` will receive the events for child elements, with `e.target` as the element that was clicked, but with `this` as the element the event was assigned to.

As the psuedo "element" is off the end of the `span` the calculations for width against the `input` and `label` are incorrect.

Changing

```
if (e.offsetX > $(e.target).width()) {
```

to

```
if (e.offsetX > $(this).width()) {
```

will use the `span`s width for the check.

Comment: Thanks again, it's funny that it was something so simple, this always seems to be the way with the issues I have :D